# Abrir una ventana al pulsar boton con dimensiones establecidas JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un menú en mi aplicación/interfaz `Java Swing`, al pulsar en el botón "`Ayuda`" quiero que se me abra el sistema de ayuda. Lo que ocurre es que me sale muy minúsculo por defecto y no sale centrado, quisiera declararle unas medidas tanto de ancho como de alto para que se pueda visualizar correctamente.

Os dejo una **imagen** de lo que ocurre:
https://s23.postimg.org/bt27k6uaz/imagen.png

Código:

```
private void lanzarAyuda(){
        try{
            //Carga el fichero de ayuda.
            File fichero = new File("sistema_ayuda" + File.separator + "helpset.hs");
            URL hsURL = fichero.toURI().toURL();

            //Crea el HelpSet.
            HelpSet helpset = new HelpSet(getClass().getClassLoader(), hsURL);
            HelpBroker hb = helpset.createHelpBroker();
            //Mostrar el sistema de ayuda al pulsar F1.
            hb.enableHelpOnButton(button_ayuda, "index", helpset);
            hb.enableHelpKey(getRootPane(), "index", helpset);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase HelpBroker tiene un metodo setSize y setLocation:

> void setLocation(java.awt.Point p) 
>             Sets the position of the presentation.
>   void    setSize(java.awt.Dimension d) 
>             Sets the size of the presentation.

Por ejemplo prueba con

> helpBroker.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
>
> helpBroker.setLocation(new Point(posX,posY));

[Más info](http://manual.openestate.org/extern/javahelp-2.0.02/api/javax/help/HelpBroker.html)